# extract string matching file from the list

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a list known as `file.out` that contain files as depicted below:

```
file                                                            a    b    c    d   e
DS_swe/msg.rti-20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt-20190415_8_2.0_rnt.txt  0.5  1.0  1.5  1.3 2.0
DS_swe/msg.rti-20105510_5_1.0_rnt.txt-20200415_8_2.0_rnt.txt  0.6  2.0  2.5  1.2 4.0
DS_swe/msg.rti-20190510_5_1.0_rnt.txt-20250415_8_2.0_rnt.txt  0.2  8.0  3.5  1.1 6.0
DS_swe/msg.rti-20102510_5_1.0_rnt.txt-20240415_8_2.0_rnt.txt  0.1  2.5  1.2  1.0 8.0
DS_swe/msg.rti-20145510_5_1.0_rnt.txt-20140415_8_2.0_rnt.txt  0.8  2.2  1.4  1.9 5.0
```

And i also have a directory named `data` that contains files like

```
data/
├── 20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt
├── 20105510_5_1.0_rnt.txt
├── 20190510_5_1.0_rnt.txt
├── 20102510_5_1.0_rnt.txt
└── 20145510_5_1.0_rnt.txt
```

These file names match with part of the above listed data part matches ex:

```
DS_swe/msg.rti-????????_?_?_???.???-20190415_8_2.0_rnt.txt 0.5  1.0  1.5  1.3 2.0.
```

Plus all the `.txt` files of the directory contain `4` rows as shown below. For example  `20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt` contains:

```
20.0  23.0  25.0  45.0  78.0  sy
14.0  12.0  24.0  45.0  78.0  tx
14.0  25.0  25.0  47.0  78.0  mx
12.0  25.0  32.0  47.0  56.0  cx
```

so what i need to do: if files(.txt) inside the directory matches with the `?` marked string of the  above list ::: then i want to extract 3rd and 4th column from the matched .txt file present inside the directory and additionally wants to extract 5th and 6th column values of the corresponding file in the list(`file.out`)  and wants to attach repeated value of same 5th and 6th column values inside the corresponding `.txt` file and finally wants to save the same `.txt` file in different directory named as `results`

For example: the expected output for the file  `20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt` would be as follows

```
25.0  45.0  1.3  2.0
24.0  45.0  1.3  2.0
25.0  47.0  1.3  2.0
32.0  47.0  1.3  2.0
```

For solving the above problem i tried the code as below but stuck on the main part where i need experts help.Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /home/lijun/data/*.txt
    grep "*.txt" file.out > file
    cat file | if
```

Comment: This is stretching in many directions. In the future, please try to focus on one problem at a time. See also the guidance for reducing your question to a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to include directories for input/output files based on OPs example `for` loop

---

One (somewhat) verbose solution ...

Use `awk` to pull out the filename and fields 5 & 6 from `file.out`:

```
$ awk '{ split($1,fn,"-"); print fn[2],$5,$6 }' file.out
20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt 1.3 2.0
20105510_5_1.0_rnt.txt 1.2 4.0
20190510_5_1.0_rnt.txt 1.1 6.0
20102510_5_1.0_rnt.txt 1.0 8.0
20145510_5_1.0_rnt.txt 1.9 5.0
```

Where:

- use the default input field separator of white space
- `split($1,fn,"-")` - split first field into array `fn` using `"-"` as the field separator
- `print fn[2],$5,$6` - output the filename and fields 5 & 6

We'll now loop through this list using a 2nd `awk` solution to pull out fields 3 & 4 from the file and append fields 5 & 6 (from `file.out`):

```
# OP will need to update the following variables to ensure they reference the correct directory where the input/output files are located:

$ in_dir="/home/lijun/data"
$ out_dir="/home/lijun/results"

$ while read -r fname field5 field6
do
    # I only have one file in my system so I'll print a warning about files I can't find
  
    [ ! -f "${in_dir}/${fname}" ]                                         && \
    echo "WARNING: Unable to locate file '${in_dir}/${fname}'. Skipping." && \
    continue

    echo "Processing file '${in_dir}/${fname}' ..."

    # pass fields 5 & 6 into `awk` using `-v`; print out desired fields

    awk -v f5="${field5}" -v f6="${field6}" '{ print $3,$4,f5,f6 }' "${in_dir}/${fname}" > "${out_dir}/${fname}"

done < <(awk '{ split($1,fn,"-"); print fn[2],$5,$6 }' file.out)
```

Running the above on my system generates:

```
Processing file '20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt' ...
WARNING: Unable to locate file '20105510_5_1.0_rnt.txt'. Skipping.
WARNING: Unable to locate file '20190510_5_1.0_rnt.txt'. Skipping.
WARNING: Unable to locate file '20102510_5_1.0_rnt.txt'. Skipping.
WARNING: Unable to locate file '20145510_5_1.0_rnt.txt'. Skipping.

$ cat 20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt.2
25.0 45.0 1.3 2.0
24.0 45.0 1.3 2.0
25.0 47.0 1.3 2.0
32.0 47.0 1.3 2.0
```

Comment: how can i redirect output to a directory....can u please update it

Comment: see commented out line with an example of adding the target directory as a prefix in the `out_fname` variable

Comment: but how it searches the matching files inside the directories where .txt files are present

Comment: 20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt  this kind  of files are present inside a directory

Comment: i want to extract 3rd and 4th column from the matched .txt file present inside the directory ....but u have not mentioned any directory where it searches .txt files

Comment: there's no mention in the question as to where the script will be run from, so there's no way (for me) to know if you'll be using a relative or explicit path; inside the `for` loop you're more than welcome to append a directory on the front of `in_file` (eg, `in_file="/source/data/directory/${in_file}"`; again, all of this depends on how you want to manage directories in your script and where you'll be running your script from (in the case of using a relative directory)

Comment: updated with assumption that the `data` and `results` directories are located under `/home/lijun/`; if this is incorrect simply update the `in_dir` and `out_dir` variables

Comment: you're welcome to modify a copy of the code to eliminate the `for/while` loop if you want; if you have problems getting said modification working correctly then I'd suggest posting a new question ...

Answer (score 0):

You could parse file.out with a first awk to get all lines whose first column matches the following **regex** pattern:

```
/DS_swe\/msg.rti-(.+)-[0-9]{8}_[0-9]_[0-9].[0-9]_rnt.txt/
```

Here, `(.+)` catches the filename and stores it into `\1`.

So the awk line to run would be:

```
awk '{
       # Replace the first column with only the related filename in datas
       # and store it in f.
       f=gensub(/DS_swe\/msg.rti-(.+)-[0-9]{8}_[0-9]_[0-9].[0-9]_rnt.txt/,
                "\\1", "1", $1)
       # If the value doesn't match the pattern, f will contain the column value
       # So don't print anything.
       if  (f != $1) print f" "$5" "$6
     } < file.out'
```

You'll get lines like:

```
20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt 1.3 2.0
```

Then get each column values with `read`:

```
read f c5 c6 # stores the filename in $f, the 5th column in $c5, the 6th in $c6
```

At least, run the another awk with those values:

```
# Parse data/"$f" file and for each line
# print the 3rd and 4th columns with "$c5 $c6" text
awk '{ print $3" "$4" '"$c5 $c6"'" }' <data/$f
```

Then you can process the output with a second awk call:

Final working sample (`&&` stands for a logical `AND`; if read doesn't encounter an end of file, then run the following command):

```
awk '{
       f=gensub(/DS_swe\/msg.rti-(.+)-[0-9]{8}_[0-9]_[0-9].[0-9]_rnt.txt/, "\\1",
                "1", $1)
       if  (f != $1) print f" "$5" "$6
      }' < file.out | {
                        read f c5 c6 &&
                        awk '{ print $3" "$4" '"$c5 $c6"'" }' <data/$f ;
                      }
```

Result:

```
25.0 45.0 1.3 2.0
24.0 45.0 1.3 2.0
25.0 47.0 1.3 2.0
32.0 47.0 1.3 2.0
```

Comment: in this code i need to extract many files not only 20160510_5_1.0_rnt.txt 1.3 2.0.....how to automate it ....as u mentioned only (.+)-20190415_8_2.0_rnt.txt

Comment: @lijun, edited answer. By the way you really should try in the first place to understand what's going on in the given code.